# How to get unique years, date, month values from the JSON data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, filter

How to get unique years, date, month values from the JSON data in angularjs. Here is sample data.

```
   data = [
     {
          "x": "2012-12-05",
          "y": 3
     },
     {
          "x": "2013-10-06",
          "y": 6
     },
     {
          "x": "2011-12-27",
          "y": 7
     },
     {
          "x": "2000-11-28",
          "y": 2
     },
     {
          "x": "2001-08-9",
          "y": 6
     },
     {
          "x": "2002-05-10",
          "y": 11
     },
     {
          "x": "2005-01-11",
          "y": 5
     }
   ]
```

I need something like this,

```
[ {year:2012,months:[12]},
  {year:2013,months: [10] },
  {year:2011, months: [11,12] }
  ....
]
```

Can I do this using angularjs?

Comment: Am I missing something, or has this nothing to do with Angular?

Comment: And how is the output related to the input?

Comment: This is not an angular question at all, this is a pure javascript function